# QlickView Botones - Macros

Tags: botón, macros

Estoy trabajando en Qlikview y tengo un botón que corre una macro que crea carpetas.

Pero necesito hacer mas botones dentro del mismo documento Qlikview que copien y peguen unos archivos (eso ya está hecho)

Entonces, necesito al menos 10 botones dentro del documento Qlikview, y cuando creo otro botón, adquiere automáticamente el script del botón ya creado (el que crea carpetas)

Cómo puedo solucionar eso?

**Este es el código VBscript que crea carpeta**:

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso,a 


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FolderExists("U:\FTP\Revenue_Management\Archivos_de_Salida\Sem_"& Year(Date) & Right("0" & Month(Date),2) & Right("0" & Day(Date),2) &"")=True     Then

a=msgbox("Carpeta ya Existe")

Else
fso.CreateFolder "U:\FTP\Revenue_Management\Archivos_de_Salida\Sem_"& Year(Date) & Right("0" & Month(Date),2) & Right("0" & Day(Date),2) &""
msgbox("Carpeta Creada")
End If
```

**Este es el código que copia los archivos**:

```
Option Explicit
dim ruta1, ruta_final,a, oFSO
ruta1 = "U:\FTP\Revenue_Management\E_Mailing\Archivos_de_Entrada\Empresarios\Sem_"& Year(Date) & Right("0" & Month(Date),2) & Right("0" & Day(Date),2) &"\*.html"
ruta_final = "U:\FTP\Revenue_Management\Archivos_de_Salida\Sem_"& Year(Date) & Right("0" & Month(Date),2) & Right("0" & Day(Date),2) &""

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If (oFSO.FileExists("ruta1"))=False Then
 oFSO.CopyFile (ruta1) , (ruta_final)
 Msgbox("Archivo copiado")
Else

 Msgbox("Archivo no existe")
 end If
```